# String refusing to concatenate?

Tags: python

To preface this, I'm trying to build [an enigma machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) in python just to kinda challenge myself, and to mess around with encrypting messages

However I run into a problem with the final loop which actually encrypts the message.

```
def encMess():
searching = True
searchPins = True
changeRotor = True
finalMess = ""
incMess = -1
while searching == True:
    print("Searching...")
    while searchPins == True:
        print("Searching Pins...")
        incMess = incMess + 1
        incPins = 0
        if incMess == len(message)-1:
            searchPins = False
        else:
            while incPins < len(initPins):
                print("Incrementing Pins...")
                if message[incMess] in initPins[incPins]:
                    if message[incMess] == initPins[incPins][0]:
                        finalMess = finalMess + initPins[incPins][1]
                    else:
                        finalMess = finalMess + initPins[incPins][0]
                incPins = incPins + 1
                print(finalMess)
    if len(finalMess) == len(message):
        searching = False
```

It just gets stuck in a loop of "Searching..." when I run the whole thing. The message variable is just "thisisatestmessage", but the thing loops through twice before stopping if I just run the inner loops, without the outer while loop which changes the letter and resets the pin counter. Could it be because I'm just using two pins in the initPins array? Because the finalMess variable ends up just being blank. Any help is appreciated

EDIT: Here's the creation of any and all variables used:

```
    global initPins
    initPins = [["a","b"],["t","z"]]
    global finalMess
    finalMess = ""
    global message
    message = "thisisatestmessage"
```

It's messy, I know. Still starting and trying my organization style

Comment: Please show the definition of `initPins`

Comment: And message, for that matter.

Comment: @HackSaw Added. Sorry bout that.

Comment: @cricket_007 Added, sorry my guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner logic,

```
if message[incMess] in initPins[incPins]:
    if message[incMess] == initPins[incPins][0]:
        finalMess = finalMess + initPins[incPins][1]
    else:
        finalMess = finalMess + initPins[incPins][0]
incPins = incPins + 1
```

if you have a letter in the pins which isn't mapped, the routine falls down to the incPins + 1 line, then proceeds to the next letter in the message, writing **nothing** to the final message. Thus final message length never equals the starting message length, and so you never stop.

BTW, I figured this out with the python debugger, PDB, via my IDE. It's a good tool.

Also, your `if len(finalMess) == len(message):` needs to be indented in a block to be checked at the right level.

Oh yeah: you can list more than one symbol in a `global` statement.

Here's the slightly edited version which stops. I've added a short sleep so I could see outputs as they came by, rather than having them scroll off the screen.

```
import time

global initPins
initPins = [["a", "b"], ["t", "z"]]
global finalMess
finalMess = "X"
global message
message = "thisisatestmessage"


def encMess():
    searching = True
    searchPins = True
    changeRotor = True
    finalMess = ""
    incMess = -1
    while searching == True:
        print("Searching...")
        time.sleep(.25 )
        while searchPins == True:
            print("Searching Pins...")
            incMess = incMess + 1
            incPins = 0
            print(incMess, len(message)-1)
            if incMess == len(message)-1:
                searchPins = False
            else:
                while incPins < len(initPins):
                    print("Incrementing Pins...")
                    if message[incMess] in initPins[incPins]:
                        if message[incMess] == initPins[incPins][0]:
                            finalMess = finalMess + initPins[incPins][1]
                    else:
                        finalMess = finalMess + initPins[incPins][0]
                    incPins = incPins + 1
                    print(finalMess, len(finalMess), len(message) )

            if len(finalMess) == len(message):
                searching = False



encMess()
```